# How to set up a mock in Foq that returns an async<T>?

Tags: f#, foq

I try to set up a mock using

```
Mock<Interface>.With(fun y -> <@ y.DoIt (any()) --> async {()} @>)
```

This leads to a `NotSupportedException` being raised in the function `toCall`.

How should I mock Async in Foq?

Is it supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: yes Foq supports returning an async block.

Issue is under discussion here: https://foq.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic

Looks like the exception was raised as the arguments to DoIt were partially applied.